# How to display only About Component Content in '/about' Router of Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components

It is a basic app and I have AppComponent by default. I have used --routing flag to generate routing for Angular 6 App.
I have generated 'AboutComponent' to place about us page content. However, Along with the About Us page content, the '/about' is also displaying AppComponent content. like below

Welcome to HomePage.
This is about us page.

How to avoid **AppComponent/any other** component content in '/about' route?

I have same problem with '/contact'.

Welcome to HomePage
This is contact us page.

Should we even keep HomePage content in AppComponent? Please clarify this, thanks in advance.

app.component.html :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Welcome to Home Page</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

about.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the .ts file of the appComponent and homepageComponent, the problem seems to be due to the placement of router-outlet

Comment: I have added the code in the question for AppComponent (Homepage) and AboutComponent (about us page).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong in your code, since I need more information, but routing of components in angular is done as such.

In your app.module.ts , specify the path and the component names and add it to the import statement

```
import {Router, RouterLink,Routes, RouterModule, RouterLinkActive} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './about/aboutus.component';

const routes: Routes =
[
  {path:'Home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'AboutUs',component:AboutUsComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full' } <== this code makes sure Home component opens by default

]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutUsComponent,    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
```

Then in your app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Reason is that your app.component.ts has a defined tag such as  `<app-root></app-root>` which is placed in your index.html file, due to which it involuntarily renders. So we use the app.component.html as a file to place those elements that we want always to render and `<router-outlet>` will render those elements that might change on navigation

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is positioning of `<router-outlet>`. Looking at your description, looks like you have router outlet in home page. so home page will be constant while routing. If you want to change the complete view along with home-page, you have to provide router outlet in the parent of home-page and have to provide valid route for home page too!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!. It seems, I should not use AppComponent as HomePage. I removed home page content from AppComponent html (just kept  tags) and it is working now. '/about' has only about content and '/contact' has only contact content. I created new HomeComponent and placed all my home page content and set it as default route. Thanks for your answers they were helpful.

Comment: Great ! you can upvote an answer and declare it as accepted so people can identify what was the solution.